# Cannot echo environment variable with space after storing in variable

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell prompt, I cannot seem to echo a system environment variable that has a space in it, stored in a variable.

For instance, if I do a simple:

```
echo ${env:My Var}
```

I get back the value of that environment variable - which is the word "test". That works great.

Then, if I echo a preset variable that is set to the string "My Var", I get back what I'd expect, the word "My Var".

```
echo $variable
```

If I then echo a hybrid of the two:

```
echo env:${variable}
```

I also get back what I'd expect, which is the string value "env:My Var".

But now I want to use that $variable to output the value of the corresponding environment variable.  Meaning, I want to use something like:

```
echo ${env:${variable}}
```

... and get back the value of the environment variable, the word "test".

But that doesn't work.  I get a red error saying *Use `{ instead of { in variable names*. But nothing like that works either.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: (get-item env:$variable).Value

Comment: Thanks @KoryGill. Based off this, I used echo (get-item env:$variable).value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
cd env:
new-item 'test 123' -Value "123"
${env:test 123}

123
$var = 'test 123'
(Get-item env:$var).value
123
(Get-item env:$var).name
Test 123
```

Comment: Based off this, I used echo (get-item env:$variable).value